# Unity calling methods on new scene

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a game with a bunch of scenes, I load them and then do DoNotDestroy so I keep them (awake/start get called the first time).

Let's say we have following state changes - menu -> game -> game over -> menu -> game...

I want to call a method when the scene is shown each time to reset/set some values.

What's the cleanest way to do this? Currently I'm doing it with the update method, but it takes a bunch of lines and it's wasteful to use Update() in every script when you don't need to.

Comment: Consider adding some example code.

Comment: You can't call `DoNotDestroy` on a Scene object. I suspect you mean you do it on a `GameObject` that some scripts are attached to.  In any case, somewhere in your code you are calling `LoadScene`, just call the `ResetValues()` method on your never-destroyed-object from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MultiSceneEditing.html) on Multiple Scene Editing, it's recommended that you avoid DontDestroyOnLoad.

> It is recommended to avoid using `DontDestroyOnLoad` to persist manager
>   GameObjects that you want to survive across scene loads. Instead,
>   create a manager scene that has all your managers and use
>   `SceneManager.LoadScene(<path>, LoadSceneMode.Additive)` and
>   `SceneManager.UnloadScene` to manage your game progress.

Therefore, in your case, you could handle resetting data in a number of ways. But one simple way would be to check the name of the scene that was just loaded, from a component in your "Manager" scene. E.g. MySceneManager in BaseScene. In the code following, we're making use of the `sceneLoaded` delegate of `SceneManager`.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class MySceneManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnEnable ( ) => SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnSceneLoaded;

    void OnSceneLoaded ( Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode )
    {
        switch ( scene.name.ToLower ( ) )
        {
            case "menu":
                // Do some "menu" initialisation here...
                break;

            case "game":
                // Do some "game" initialisation here...
                break;

            case "gameover":
                // Do some "gameover" initialisation here...
                break;
        }
    }

    void OnDisable ( ) => SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= OnSceneLoaded;
}
```

N.B. This method unfortunately won't have compile-time checking of your scene names, so you'll have to be careful to make sure your scene names correspond to the switch cases.

But, another thing the remember is that any component in your newly loaded scene will have `Awake()` called anyway, so you could just offload all of your scene initialisation to a component in each scene. This would decouple MySceneManager from the data in each scene.

So, you've got quite a few options, these being just two of them. The "best" option will be the one you're comfortable with, and that suits your needs.

Comment: Ye I do all in Awake(), but then when I load the scene the 2nd time I gotta reset some values, though there was a method in MonoBehaviour to call it but there isn't. But anyway the way you just showed me is perfect actually! Did in this way when I was using libGDX.